# R osm_extract package not handling railway tag properly

Tags: r, openstreetmap, ogr2ogr, pbf, other-tags

I am working with files from OpenStreetMaps obtained from GeoFabrik in the .osm.pbf format. My goal is to use the osmextract package from R to filter the files to only include certain tags. The package works well for the most part, as I am able to filter the document and transform it to a .gpkg format. However, I consistently encounter the same issue for extracting the railway tag. In theory, once I run the function oe_read, the package uses the osmconfig.ini file from GDAL to define the tags that receive their own column in the .gpkg output file. Tags like highway, waterway and barrier are properly handled, but the column for the railway tag is never generated. I have already checked the content of the .ini file to make sure that railway is defined as one of the tags (I also tried using a costume .ini file). In addition, I am sure that the file I am working contains elements with the tag railway. I could confirm that the railway tag is simply being attached to the 'other_tags' column (together with various other unimportant tags) instead of properly receiving its own. At this point, I don't really know what to do to ensure the file is properly transformed.

The code and output structure of the file for your reference:

```
library(pacman)
p_load(sf,osmextract,osmdata,dplyr,stringr)

NLD_file <- "data/osm/netherlands-2018.osm.pbf"

NLD_osm_data <- oe_read(NLD_file)
```

```
str(NLD_osm_data)
Classes ‘sf’ and 'data.frame':  1532763 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ osm_id    : chr  "2161182" "2952999" "2953564" "2953622" ...
 $ name      : chr  "Jutfaseweg" "Pieter Bernagiestraat" "Timorkade" "Vredesteeg" ...
 $ highway   : chr  "footway" "footway" "cycleway" "footway" ...
 $ waterway  : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ aerialway : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ barrier   : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ man_made  : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ z_order   : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ other_tags: chr  "\"loc_name\"=>\"Wittestenensteeg\"" "\"bicycle\"=>\"no\"" "\"foot\"=>\"yes\"" "\"foot\"=>\"yes\"" ...
 $ geometry  :sfc_LINESTRING of length 1532763; first list element:  'XY' num [1:2, 1:2] 5.12 5.12 52.07 52.07
 - attr(*, "sf_column")= chr "geometry"
 - attr(*, "agr")= Factor w/ 3 levels "constant","aggregate",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:9] "osm_id" "name" "highway" "waterway" ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `extra_tags = "railway"` seems to get railway items.

I'm using just the Groningen PBF here, freshly downloaded from https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/netherlands/groningen.html

```
NLD_file = "./groningen-latest.osm.pbf"
NLD_osm_data <- oe_read(NLD_file, extra_tags="railway")
rail = NLD_osm_data[!is.na(NLD_osm_data$railway),]
```

Then mapping with `mapview`:

```
library(mapview)
mapview(rail)
```

[image]

I don't know if you tried this and it didn't work, but this works for me. I don't think I've changed any other config or `.ini` file, certainly not in my memory...

Comment: thank you for reply. Indeed, I did not try the extra_tag option and it does solve the issue. I am still a bit puzzled by the fact that the oe_read function needs railway to be defined separately, even though the ini file defines railway as one of the default elements.